# Configuring NGINX + uWSGI + Django in a multi-tenancy application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, uwsgi, multi-tenant

I have a single application in django hosted on AWS. But, in these days, I turned It into multi-tenancy, using django-tenant-schemas. Locally, It runs normally. I can create my tenants and access them on my local django server. However, I'm not getting to run on AWS.

My **.conf** file for **NGINX** looks like this:

```sh
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu/folder_my_projct/mysite.sock; # for a file s$
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80; address or $
    server_name ssh *.example.com.br;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/folder_my_projct/media;  # your Django project's$
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/folder_my_projct/static; # your Django project's$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/folder_my_projct/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi$
    }
}
```

I did pull for my project that runs on AWS, everything worked in my Virtual Machine (makemigrations and migrate_schemas). However, when I try to access the subdomain, It doesn't work. My only change to access the subdomains was in the file above, pasting the ***** before the dot: `* .example.com.br`. I tried using regex, but it didn't work as too (`server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com\.br $;`). I do really appreciate if someone tells me what I'm doing wrong, or if I need to do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line `server_name ssh *.example.com.br;`

by

- `server_name ssh.example.com.br *.example.com.br;`
- or `server_name *.example.com.br;`

---

For each subdomain you'll need to create a configuration, depending what you want to access

```
server {
  server_name ssh.example.com.br;
  ...
}

server {
  server_name blabla.example.com.br;
  ...
}

server {
  server_name *.example.com.br;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your answer! Thanks a lot! I'm gonna travel in the next days, but I'm sure that your answer will help me! When I try again, I come back here and check.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have the same issue. Does that mean that ssl certificates need to be created as well for each tenant?

Comment: request a wilcard certificates like `*.example.com.br`, that will avoid to request one for each new subdomain (that is possible too)